# Timer and TimerTask in android - further understanding

Tags: java, android, api

I'm building an app using camera2 API. Now I'm referencing [Google samples in github](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2video/Camera2VideoFragment.java). The problem is I couldn't understand why `Timer` and `TimerTask` classes used when stopping currently recording video. Hope help in here. Thank you.

Here The Code :

```
 private void stopRecordingVideo() {
    // UI
    mIsRecordingVideo = false;
    mButtonVideo.setText(R.string.record);
    // Stop recording
    try {
        mPreviewSession.stopRepeating();
        mPreviewSession.abortCaptures();
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mMediaRecorder.stop();
            mMediaRecorder.reset();
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(timerTask,30);

    startPreview();
}
```

I just want to know that


**1. How the `Timer` and `TimeTask` is working

2. How the above classes combine with each other

3. An additionally what is the major role in this method?**

Comment: Can you link the file? I can't seem to find a class with TimerTask anywhere in the repository you linked.

Comment: @HristoStoyanov I put the link to the repository. But now I've changed it to the class file link. Now you can see the whole context

Comment: There's still no TimerTask , the stopRecordingVideo() method is quite different in the link.

Comment: Sure @HristoStoyanov. That part I added later bcoz while the app is recording video when pressing the stop button, the application will stop unexpectedly. When I searched what was the error, I found that the missing part. When I added this part it worked correctly. Unfortunately, I couldn't find out right now from where I was found it. Sorry for that. I didn't bookmark it. However, I want to know what the main task of the given part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it should be made clear that [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) and [TimerTask](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) are parts of `java.util`, not belong to Android framework.
**1. How the Timer and TimerTask is working**
`TimerTask` is an utility class which implements `Runnable` to override `run` method to perform your defined task. Meanwhile, `Timer` helps you to schedule time and execute that task. Besides, your task will be performed in a background thread.
**2. How the above classes combine with each other**
As described above, `TimerTask` will define your actual task and `Timer` will set an alarm to execute it.
**3. An additionally what is the major role in this method?**
When you call `stopRecordingVideo()`, Timer is used here to turn off `MediaRecorder` in **background thread** after 30 milliseconds. As I thought, the main purpose of using `Timer` here to execute `MediaRecorder.stop()` in a background threa rather than UI thread.

Comment: After I pressed STOP button in 30miliseconds will turn off Media recorder. That means to start the stopping video process will take 30milisecods. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. It will invoke everything inside TimerTask `run` method after scheduled time (here is 30 milliseconds). You can test it by change it to 2000 or 3000 and see that it will be delayed more.

Comment: If we don't need any delay can we set that value to null?

Comment: `delay` parameter is a primitive `long` type. You can not set it to null. Instead, you should set it to `0` to remove delay.

Comment: Sure, Thanks again